# Submit Two Adobe Air Mac Apps in single package to App Store

Tags: air, app-store

I have created an objective-c app that will launch embedded adobe air apps properly (sandboxed, etc). I'm able to create an archive through Xcode that embeds the apps. When submitting the archive/package to the Mac App Store, the validation process fails because both AIR apps use the Adobe Air Framework, and the bundle identifiers conflict (used more than once). I've tried manipulating the bundle identifier names, used the 'PREFIX' option when codesign-ing before validation with no luck.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this conflict?

Comment: SOLUTION: If you remove the WebKit.dylib and Adobe AIR.vch from the Adobe AIR.Framework package, you can submit two AIR apps bundled together.

Comment: ADDITION: also remove A2712Enabler.  Removing these is also helpful if submitting just a single app.